# TabHost is deprecated

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I notice that `TabHost` is deprecated.

[image]

But, when I run my application in my mobile. I notice that it properly working with no error.

Why? In which android version `TabHost` won't work.

My android version : Lollipop/5.1,   Android API level : 22.

Should I work with it? Or, I have to use `ViewPager` and `TabLayout`.

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tab_host"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/rl_">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Filters"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include
                    layout="@layout/filters_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Adjustments"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#40cccccc" />

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: `TabHost` was deprecated for some reason, it's always best to avoid using deprecated classes and migrate to currently supported/suggested

Comment: `I notice that it properly working with no error.` sure, deprecated doesn't mean that it won't work, it's just saying it might be removed soon and you should find the alternative

Comment: @a_local_nobody What's the better alternative of it?

Comment: @snachmsm What's the better alternative of it?

Comment: i don't think there's anything like a tab host anymore, perhaps a viewpager

Comment: @a_local_nobody I didn't use `TabActivity`. I am just working with `FrameLayout`, `TabWidget` and `TabHost`.

Comment: @a_local_nobody Check my source code. I think I can use the source code, can't I?

Comment: deprecated really just means there's probably a better/newer way of doing something, it doesn't mean your code won't work, that's the link i sent you.

Comment: @a_local_nobody Does it mean I can use it in every Android Version?