# Alternative of TabHost

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tabhost, android-tablayout

[image: TabLayout]
[image: TabLayout]
[image: TabHost]

Here as you can see I used `TabLayout`,`TabHost`. I used `TabLayout` in first twice pictures. In third picture I used `TabHost`. Usually, `TabLayout` is looking better than `TabHost`/`TabWidget`.[TabHost](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost) as you can see `TabHost` is deprecated. So, It would be better if I don't use `TabHost`. [`TabLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout) isn't deprecated. Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65915983/tabhost-is-deprecated) I asked someone said it is duplicate. I thought it was. Look, while I am using `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` I can't use those `layout` directly in `MainActivity` I meant I have to write source code inside those `framgents` class to work right there. But, while I am using `TabHost`,`TabWidget` and `TabContent` I can use those `layouts` directly in `MainActivity` I don't have to write source code somewhere else. Like I used in `ViewPager` or `Fragments`. So, it is the problem between `TabLayout` and `TabHost`. And, `TabHost` or `TabWidget` isn't scrollable which means I can't scroll `TabWidget` like I did in `TabLayout`. There's another problem arise. So, `TabLayout` and `TabHost` isn't same. So, it would be better if I don't use `TabLayout` alternative of `Tabhost`.

In my project I need scrollable tabs like `TabLayout` and, I have to access those layouts from my `MainActivity`. So, I can't use `TabLayout`. Although I tried to use it. But, is there any possible way to use only layouts inside `ViewPager` and access those layouts from `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was terrible question I had asked. There's better way to do it. I was thinking how to do that. Then, I used `TabLayout` and `FrameLayout`. I thought `FrameLayout` will hide others linearlayout without first `layout`. Then, I had added to my `activity_main.xml`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>


<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tabitem1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Monday" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tabitem2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tuesday" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tabitem3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wednesday" />
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

But, `FrameLayout` didn't work as I thought. So, I discouraged again. But, I keep thinking of it. I didn't remove anything. Then, something else came to my head. What if I hide others `linearLayout` without first ones. How I thought `Framelayout` should work. Then, I set on `LinearLayout` `Visibility = "GONE"`.

```
LinearLayout l1 = findViewById(R.id.tab1);
    LinearLayout l2 = findViewById(R.id.tab2);
    LinearLayout l3 = findViewById(R.id.tab3);

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            Log.d("TAB_POSITION", String.valueOf(tab.getPosition()));
            if (tab.getPosition()==0){
                l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (l2.getVisibility()==View.GONE){

                }else{
                    l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                if (l3.getVisibility()==View.GONE){

                }else{
                    l3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }else if (tab.getPosition()==1){
                l2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (l1.getVisibility()==View.GONE){

                }else{
                    l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                if (l3.getVisibility()==View.GONE){

                }else{
                    l3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }else if (tab.getPosition()==2){
                l3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (l2.getVisibility()==View.GONE){

                }else{
                    l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                if (l1.getVisibility()==View.GONE){

                }else{
                    l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

So, while I am clicking on another `tabs` it is hiding others layout without main ones. So, it worked for me. There's no alternative I have get. I will say that it is my answer.